# Searching call stacks in Visual Studio

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, debugging, search, callstack

I am using Visual Studio to debug a large multithreaded C++ application. I am trying to find out what thread ran a function I am interested in.

I have more than 40 threads, some with really lengthy call stacks. So, manually inspecting individual call stacks to see if they contain my function is really tedious.

I was wondering if Visual Studio supports searching call stacks like it supports searching source files. Could you please tell me how to search call stacks in VS?

Comment: My Googling turned up another question that looks to have an answer already: [How to dump or search in call stacks of ALL threads in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812645/how-to-dump-or-search-in-call-stacks-of-all-threads-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I don't know of any way to search the call stack from within Visual Studio's viewer window.

I use a rather low-tech solution for this: with the Call Stack window focused, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Switch to a text editor with the desired search wrangling features, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Yup, good old copy-and-paste. It works. Obtaining a textual representation of the call stack has several other advantages, including the ability to save different call stacks, diff them, and post them to Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that I'll need to copy paste 40 times because I have 40 threads, hence 40 call stacks? GDB allows you to print the output of `bt` for all threads to a text file using one command. Something like that would be nice.

Comment: Is there a way to collate all call stacks into one, so I could do a single copy-paste in one fell swoop?  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, good question. I haven't ever had a need to deal with that many threads at once. You may need something more high-tech. :-) I assume you have tried the Parallel Stacks window? Not sure if you can copy-paste from there, though.

Comment: You mention GDB. The Windows equivalent is probably WinDbg, rather than Visual Studio. If you prefer the command line world, you'll probably be more at home there. There's definitely a way to do this in WinDbg. I forget the exact command; you can look it up in the documentation.

Comment: @TheVivandiere : I'm dealing with a crash dump with 100+ threads and this is how I make this Low-Tech method works. Go to Debug->Windows->Threads. Then click "expand CallStacks". Now you can copy all call stack at once.