# Is there any way to capture the call stack windows (vs2005) into text file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, callstack

I use visual studio 2005 and try to get some information at "call stack window".

I have got what I want through "call stack window".
However, I want to know is there any way to get context in "call stack window" for further use.
[Namely, I want to get "Name" column in this call stack by "codes".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84jMx.png)

Ideally, I want to capture the call stack information and save it as txt file through code.

```
if(capture_flag == true){ /* using code to get call stack information and save as txt file */ }
```

I had checked dozens of article and I have not find the way to do that.
Most of "stackwalker" function is not working in vs2005.
The most related article is [How to dump or search in call stacks of ALL threads in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812645/how-to-dump-or-search-in-call-stacks-of-all-threads-in-visual-studio).

Please give me feedbacks if there is anyway to access "call stack window" through code.
The information I want is "functions be called and line no." at the particular point.
Thanks.

Comment: boost and abseil both have a stacktrace library but i doubt either of them works in VS2005. May I ask why youre using such an old version?

Comment: "*capture the call stack information and save it as txt file through code*" Why? If you want to capture the state, save a crash dump file then you can get *all* available information out of it, any time you want.

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks, I will check both library you mentioned. As for vs2005, this is because I am dealing with old factory system.

Comment: @dxiv Since I want to use this information(e.g., function name, line no.) in other places. txt file is good for me to do that. In my imagination, I could easily get what I want as I have saw them in call stack window, but it seems to be a difficult job now.

Comment: @RoySung Use them how exactly? Walking the stack symbolically from *inside* your code is virtually always the wrong solution to whatever problem you hope to solve.

Comment: Check out [MiniDumpWriteDump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/nf-minidumpapiset-minidumpwritedump?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: @dxiv I am not dealing with problem in the codes. The reason why I want to print out the information is because I want to add codes into existing vs2005 projects and there are hundred them. I want to locate function name and line no., then I can easily write a tool to do that.

Comment: I suggest that you could refer to Microsoft Docs about [StackFrame Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stackframe?view=net-5.0). Hope it will be useful to you